# react native home/recentApp/back button set disable

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

i want to lock my app on screen when user click on back/home/recentApp click none of them work , i simply controlled back button but about others i didn't find any thing can anybody help me?

**i coding react native**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Home and other system buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android)

Comment: You can not controll home,recentApp button in android, but you can handle backbutton press by using [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler)

Comment: You cannot disable home and recent button, Instead use fullscreen mode  & draw a transparent layout on top of navbar to listen touch events. This is not recommended obviously !

Comment: i found a solution like this but there isn't good hint for implement do you have any link about concept? @Firu

Comment: [Did you tried these ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native)

Comment: yes but my mainActivity extend navigationActivity so it dosent override those methods :( @Firu