# How to hide android system' s bottom navigation bar in React Native App without changing MainActivity? Maybe through AndroidManifest?

Tags: javascript, react-native, build-error, android-navigation-bar

I want to hide the system's bottom navigation bar. I used "react-native-navigation-bar-color" but it causes a build error, strangely while release build only.

I thought I could remove this package(react-native-navigation-bar-color) and permanently hide the navbar by changing MainActivity but the MainActivity in React Native does not inherit AppCompatActivity in order for it to have "onCreate" method in which I can write the code(as per android studio documentation) to hide.

Following is the build error:
/Users/yashjaveri/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/f688ce916ebedb5188b6c1f4470868ef/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerR
adius not found.

/Users/yashjaveri/Documents/React/ReactNative_Projects/SLink/node_modules/react-native-navigation-bar-color/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/yashjaveri/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/f688ce916ebedb5188b6c1f4470868ef/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/yashjaveri/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/f688ce916ebedb5188b6c1f4470868ef/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation-bar-color:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Please help me out either by providing way to hide navbar permanently in react-native or by suggesting any other npm package() or by helping me solve the release build error, as my app has a video screen which requires full screen mode.

Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you share screenshot ? When we create a new react native app there is no nav-bar by default.

Comment: Alright I will add screenshot

Comment: I have added the Screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hide the Navigation Bar**

You can hide the navigation bar using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag. This snippet hides both the navigation bar and the status bar:

ote the following:

```java
@Reactmethod
public void hidenavigationbar() {
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

- With this approach, touching anywhere on the screen causes the
  navigation bar (and status bar) to reappear and remain visible. The
  user interaction causes the flags to be be cleared.
- Once the flags have been cleared, your app needs to reset them if you
  want to hide the bars again. See Responding to UI Visibility Changes
  for a discussion of how to listen for UI visibility changes so that
  your app can respond accordingly.
- Where you set the UI flags makes a difference. If you hide the system
  bars in your activity's onCreate() method and the user presses Home,
  the system bars will reappear. When the user reopens the activity,
  onCreate() won't get called, so the system bars will remain visible.
  If you want system UI changes to persist as the user navigates in and
  out of your activity, set UI flags in onResume() or
  onWindowFocusChanged().
- The method setSystemUiVisibility() only has an effect if the view you
  call it from is visible.
- Navigating away from the view causes flags set with
  setSystemUiVisibility() to be cleared.

[this link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation?hl=es#java) about my answer

OR
Use this [link](https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-full-screen)

```js
import FullScreen from 'react-native-full-screen'
FullScreen.onFullScreen()
FullScreen.offFullScreen()
```

an article referenced in writing [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45073594/11212074).

Comment: Thank you, but I am using react-navigation and not react-native-navigation. Any idea with that?

Comment: could you try this ? `tabBarVisible: false`?

Comment: My app doesn't have a tab bar. I am intended to hide the System's Navigation bar  both aren't the same thing I guess.

Comment: I've thought about it in the process of modifying the above answers, but Could you try use the function of my answers using @Reactmethod?

Comment: Or try this 'react-native-full-screen'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192123/discussion-between-yash-javeri-and-hong-develop).