# How to identify the android bottom navigation using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

**Hi everyone, I'm new in react native,
     So eager to know that how to identify android bottom navigation is set or not. 
    Your help will be appreciated.
    Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: what do you mean by android bottom navigation, any example?

Comment: Please have a look into this URL: -  https://prnt.sc/qpd7be

Comment: I want to identify for my app is softbar are apearing on my screen or not?, Using react native. What function should I use to identify this?

Comment: does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native