# How do I remove the home button navigation on mobile in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-safeareaview

I've been making my mobile application in React Native and noticed that the home button and the bottom navigation bar for Android was overriding the app and pushing it up making it look weird. Is there a safe area view but for the bottom navigation bar in React Native?

The Android default navigation bar is here: https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/11/android-60-google-now-home-button-shortcut-100628113-primary.idge.jpg?auto=webp&quality=85,70

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Android Navigation Bar in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native)

Comment: possible to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

[You can try this latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68158639/7578825). There are many way to achieve this. Look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native).

react-native-system-navigation-bar

Install

> yarn add react-native-system-navigation-bar

or

> npm install react-native-system-navigation-bar