# How can I hide the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to hide the Bottom Navigation Bar or make it transparent so that View take full screen.

Is there any way to do this?

[image: Bottom Navigation Bar to change]

I'm expecting that it will auto hide when not in use. It should only be visible when user want to use the navigation like in Youtube when we watch video in Landscape view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077439/20325571
You will need to install a new package :
`npm install react-native-navigation-bar-color`

Then, you will need to import

```js
import {
  HideNavigationBar,
  ShowNavigationBar,
} from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';
```

And these methods will be available :
`ShowNavigationBar();`
And
`HideNavigationBar();`

Comment: It's about hiding the header bar but I want to hide the Navigation Bar which is android bottom navigation bar .

Comment: Oh sorry ! I changed my anwser !

Comment: Whenever I'm trying to call the function HideNavigationBar() , it showing that undefined is not a function.

Comment: Thank You now working actually we have to call hideNavigationBar() instead of HideNavigationBar(). The documentation of this library is little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expo's NavigationBar component to control its appearance. `setVisibilityAsync` and `setBehaviourAsync` will be the two functions you want. From the docs:

For example, if the navigation bar is hidden (setVisibilityAsync(false)) and the behavior is 'overlay-swipe', the user can swipe from the bottom of the screen to temporarily reveal the navigation bar.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/

Comment: In want to do it with React Native CLI , is there any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved the issue.

import the library [react-native-navigation-bar-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-bar-color)

Then you can use it like this.

```
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {hideNavigationBar} from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';

const BottomBar = () => {
  hide = () => {
    hideNavigationBar();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Hide bar" onPress={() => hide()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default BottomBar;
```