# Hide android navigation bar react native

Tags: react-native, navigationbar

I want to hide android navigation when calling a modal window, but I can’t do it, it is always shown when the modal is opened.

I tried solutions to this question but it didn't work ([Hide Android Navigation Bar in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046055/hide-android-navigation-bar-in-react-native))

Comment: To achieve this you will have to use a package. Give react-native-system-navigation-bar a try.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use react-native-immersive, this an example code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, Button } from 'react-native';
import Immersive from 'react-native-immersive';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Enable immersive mode when the component mounts
    Immersive.on();
    return () => {
      // Disable immersive mode when the component unmounts
      Immersive.off();
    };
  }, []);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(true);
    // Disable immersive mode when the modal is opened
    Immersive.off();
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    // Enable immersive mode when the modal is closed
    Immersive.on();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Open Modal" onPress={openModal} />
      <Modal visible={isModalVisible} animationType="slide">
        <View>
          <Text>Your Modal Content</Text>
          <Button title="Close Modal" onPress={closeModal} />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

because React Native does not provide a direct API to control the visibility of the Android navigation bar out of the box.