# How to make an Android app a device owner without using ADB and hide navigation buttons programmatically

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, device-admin

I am developing an Android app for my organization, which will not be available on the Play Store. The app will only be installed on company-owned devices. I want the app to hide the navigation "home" and "recent apps" buttons as soon as it starts, so that the user cannot exit the app.

I initially set the app as a device owner using ADB, but this approach is not feasible as a laptop may not always be available. I also tried running ADB shell commands from within the app, but that method did not work. Is there a way to set the app as a device owner without relying on ADB, or is there a different approach to hide the navigation buttons when the app starts?

Comment: for same reasons you should also hide/lock notifications tray. afaik what you want to achieve is possible only with some EMM system probably... adb way is just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Just leave your application in full screen mode as documented in this documentation -> [Android Full Screen](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive?authuser=1&hl=pt-br)

Or can you make this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51655122/9130794

Comment: op said "so that the user cannot exit the app" - your resolution makes these buttons just hide but well-known gesture (swipe from bottom) will reveal them...

Comment: Sorry but I'm sure you can't do this by code, maybe there is a way to do this as a user of the device but automatically through code, I'm sure you can't do this as it would be a huge security hole considering that any troll app could do this and ruin the cell phone.