# how to cover the Image to whole screen as my system home gesture button is showing , want to cover it with background image using react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

> [my home screen showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abwOE.jpg)
> i have used react navigation and my status bar is coming inside background image but not the bottom button which comes on my android device

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { useWindowDimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
interface SliderSwiperProps {
item: any;
}
const SliderSwiper: FC<SliderSwiperProps> = ({ item}) => {
const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
return (
<Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />
);
};
export default SliderSwiper;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
image: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
resizeMode: 'cover',
width: '100%',
},
});
```

[1]

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077439/20325571

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.